# Getting the Set with the most elements nested in a HashMap using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, set, java-stream

So here is the situation:
I need to register people's vote for certain dates. In short, a date is proposed and people vote for the date they want.

The data structure is the following:

```
private HashMap<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>> votes;
```

A vote is:

```
public class Vote {
    private String name;
    private VoteType vote;

    public Vote(String name, VoteType vote) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.vote = vote;
    }
}
```

Where VoteType is just an enum:

```
public enum VoteType {YES, NO, MAYBE}
```

Now I already made a stream that returns the amount of votes for the availability (VoteType):

```
public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> voteCount(VoteType targetVote) {
    return this.votes.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> new Integer(
            e.getValue().stream().filter(v -> v.getVote() == targetVote).collect(Collectors.toList()).size())));
}
```

So my question is:
How can I get, using Java Streams, the date that got the most 'YES'.

```
/* Returns the date that got the most 'YES' votes */
public LocalDateTime winningDate() {
    // TODO
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does a `MAYBE` vote type has a value for winningDate?

Comment: I mean if `YES` are the same we should count `MAYBE` votes?

Comment: Only the 'YES'.

Comment: There is never a reason to use `new Integer(…)`. Starting with Java 9, this constructor has been marked *deprecated*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So my question is: How can I get, using Java Streams, the date that
>   got the most 'YES'.

This is going to be a lengthy one...

1. we need to get to a position where we have a `Stream<LocalDateTime>` so we can later group by date applying a `counting` downstream collector to get the number of votes on that specific date and we can accomplish this structure via `flatMap`.
2. we need to retain only the objects where the vote type is `YES`
3. we group the results by the date and have the values as the number of `YES` votes on that specific date.
4. we stream over the `entrySet` and find the `max` date by vote

Code:

```
/* Returns the date that got the most 'YES' votes */
public Optional<LocalDateTime> getWinningDate() {
    return votes.entrySet() // Set<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Set<Vote>>
            .stream() // Stream<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Set<Vote>>
            .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().filter(a -> a.getVote() == VoteType.YES)
                         .map(x -> e.getKey())) // Stream<LocalDateTime>
           .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting())) // Map<LocaleDateTime, Long>
           .entrySet() // Set<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Long>>
           .stream() // Stream<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Long>>
           .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)) // Optional<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Long>>
           .map(Map.Entry::getKey); // Optional<LocalDateTime>
}
```

- note that I've changed the method return type to
  `Optional<LocaleDateTime>`, I could have returned
  `.map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null)` thus you've be able to maintain your current method return type of `LocalDateTime` but that just feels bad and so
  I've decided to defer the decision upon what to do in the "no value
  case" to the client.
- I've changed the method name to `getWinningDate` to enhance readability.

As for dealing with [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), in your case, if you want to have a `null` value in the case of `getWinningDate` returning an empty Optional, you can unwrap it safely as:

```
LocalDateTime winningDate = getWinningDate().orElse(null);
```

or if you want to provide a default date:

```
LocalDateTime winningDate = getWinningDate().orElse(defaultDate);
```

or if you're sure there will always be a result then simply call `get()`.

```
LocalDateTime winningDate = getWinningDate().get();
```

etc..

Comment: You are mapping to a `SimpleEntry` despite you’re not using the second value anywhere. You could simply map to `e.getKey()` here and use `Function.identity()` in the subsequent `collect(groupingBy(…))`. Or eliminate the the `flatMap` completely, like in your second answer.

Comment: @Holger as always appreciated for the useful comments. edited to accommodate your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
private LocalDateTime winningDate(Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> mapGroup) {
    Integer max = mapGroup
                    .values().stream()
                    .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                    .get();

    return mapGroup
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(max))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                    .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53771319/getting-the-set-with-the-most-elements-nested-in-a-hashmap-using-java-streams/53771478#53771478) shows a way to do it without your `voteCount` method but just in case you **may** want to write some logic in your `winningDate` method that would integrate with your already made `voteCount` method.

in which case we can do:

```
/* Returns the date that got the most 'YES' votes */
public Optional<LocalDateTime> getWinningDate() {
    return voteCount(VoteType.YES).entrySet() // call voteCount and stream over the entries
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
}
```

- first we invoke the `voteCount(VoteType.YES)` method to get a mapping of dates and the number of `YES` votes on the date.
- second we find the max `LocalDateTime` by the vote count
- note that I've changed the method return type to
  `Optional<LocaleDateTime>`, I could have returned
  `.map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null)` thus you'll be able to maintain
  your current method return type of `LocalDateTime` but that just feels
  bad and so I've decided to defer the decision upon what to do in the
  "no value case" to the client.
- I've changed the method name to `getWinningDate` to enhance
  readability.

Further, the `voteCount` method can be improved to:

```
public Map<LocalDateTime, Long> voteCount(VoteType targetVote) {
        return this.votes.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                e -> e.getValue().stream().filter(v -> v.getVote() == targetVote).count()));
}
```

this avoids the overhead of constructing a list of all the elements that pass the filter simply to retrieve the count via `size()`, instead just `filter` and invoke `count`.

Answer (score 4):

Use your first method which counts up the YES votes, returns a map of the yes counts which is passed into the winning date method:

```
/* Returns the date that got the most 'YES' votes */
public LocalDateTime winningDate(Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> yesVotes) {
    return yesVotes.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).get().getKey();
}
```

I can't help but thinking this was the intention here, but what do I know.

Answer (score 3):

You asked how to do it with streams, here's another way:

```
class Max { long value = Long.MIN_VALUE; LocalDateTime date; }
Max max = new Max();
votes.forEach((d, vs) -> {
    long count = vs.stream().filter(v -> VoteType.YES == v.getVote()).count();
    if (count > max.value) {
        max.value = count;
        max.date = d;
    }
});

LocalDateTime maxDate = max.date;
```

And to get the set of votes:

```
Set<Vote> maxVotesForYes = votes.get(maxDate);
```

This solution iterates the map entries and counts `YES` votes for each date. If this count is greater than the current max count, the max count (along with its corresponding date) is changed.

In order to be able to modify the max count and its corresponding date, we need a local class `Max` that keeps track of these values (otherwise, we wouldn't be able to change variables from within a lambda).

Comment: very imaginative as usual Federico, always thinking outside the box. +1.

Answer (score 2):

The question asked about how to solve this *"using Java Streams"*. The following **is** using streams. And a `for`-loop.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class VoteCountTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>> votes = 
            new LinkedHashMap<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>>();

        Set<Vote> yes0 = votesWith(VoteType.NO, VoteType.NO);
        Set<Vote> yes1 = votesWith(VoteType.YES, VoteType.NO);
        Set<Vote> yes2 = votesWith(VoteType.YES, VoteType.YES);

        votes.put(LocalDateTime.of(2000, 1, 1, 1, 1), yes1);
        votes.put(LocalDateTime.of(2000, 1, 2, 1, 1), yes0);
        votes.put(LocalDateTime.of(2000, 1, 3, 1, 1), yes2);
        votes.put(LocalDateTime.of(2000, 1, 4, 1, 1), yes1);

        System.out.println(getWinningDateA(votes));
        System.out.println(getWinningDateB(votes));
    }

    public static Optional<LocalDateTime> getWinningDateA(
        Map<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>> votes)
    {
        LocalDateTime bestDate = null;
        long maxCount = -1;
        Predicate<Vote> votedYes = v -> v.getVote() == VoteType.YES;
        for (Entry<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>> entry : votes.entrySet())
        {
            long count = entry.getValue().stream().filter(votedYes).count(); 
            if (count > maxCount)
            {
                maxCount = count;
                bestDate = entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(bestDate);
    }

    // As of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771478/3182664
    public static Optional<LocalDateTime> getWinningDateB(Map<LocalDateTime, Set<Vote>> votes) 
    {
        return votes.entrySet() // Set<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Set<Vote>>
                .stream() // Stream<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Set<Vote>>
                .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().filter(a -> a.getVote() == VoteType.YES)
                             .map(x -> e.getKey())) // Stream<LocalDateTime>
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())) // Map<LocaleDateTime, Long>
               .entrySet() // Set<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Long>>
               .stream() // Stream<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Long>>
               .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)) // Optional<Entry<LocaleDateTime, Long>>
               .map(Map.Entry::getKey); // Optional<LocalDateTime>
    }    


    //=========================================================================
    enum VoteType {YES, NO, MAYBE}

    static class Vote {
        private String name;
        private VoteType vote;

        public Vote(String name, VoteType vote) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.vote = vote;
        }
        public VoteType getVote()
        {
            return vote;
        }
    }

    private static Set<Vote> votesWith(VoteType... voteTypes)
    {
        Set<Vote> votes = new LinkedHashSet<Vote>();
        for (int i = 0; i < voteTypes.length; i++)
        {
            votes.add(new Vote("v" + i, voteTypes[i]));
        }
        return votes;
    }

}
```

Compare this to the "pure-stream" solution, and think about which code you'd rather like to read, understand and maintain in the future. Then choose wisely.

<sub>(I know that this may, strictly speaking, not be the desired answer to the question. But some people seem to *intentionally* over-use streams and derive some sort of geeky pride from that. I also enjoy that [as a challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/79082/41175) occasionally. But imagining that **I** might be the one who has to maintain these abominations of functional programming in the future makes me shudder...)</sub>

Comment: Lovely answer and a good read indeed +1. btw wouldnt it be better to declare the predicate --> `Predicate<Vote> votedYes = v -> v.getVote() == VoteType.YES;` before the `for` loop? so you only have to construct it once instead of creating one in each iteration.

Comment: @Aomine That's a reasonable thing to do, indeed (updated). But now you made me curious whether that's not something that the JIT could figure out... ;-)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I briefly remember reading a blog talking about something similar but not exactly sure, to be honest. I may look into that when free cause I am a bit curious as well ;-)

Comment: @Aomine Meh, looking it up is boring ;-) But admittedly, I only did a naive, quick test right now, and the compiled code for even the most trivial loops is huge when streams are involved - far too much to analyze sensibly (for me). Beyond that, considering that runtime compilation, instantiation of lambda classes and escape analysis will play together here, it'll be hard to carve out an example where "reliable" information can be obtained from. (But if you find a nice link, I'd be interested nevertheless)